# Kafka Streams error - Offset commit failed on partition, request timed out

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We use Kafka Streams for consuming, processing and producing messages, and on PROD env we faced with errors on multiple topics:

```
ERROR org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=app-xxx-StreamThread-3-consumer, groupId=app] 
Offset commit failed on partition xxx-1 at offset 13920: 
The request timed out.[]
```

These errors occur rarely for topics with small load, but for topics with high load (and spikes) errors occur dozens of times a day per topic. Topics have multiple partitions (e.g. 10). Seems this issue does not affect processing of data (despite performance), as after throwing exception (even could be multiple errors for the same offset), consumer later re-read message and successfully process it.

I see that this error message appeared in `kafka-clients` version `1.0.0` due to [PR](https://github.com/apache/kafka/commit/6896f1ddb7650f42630aef8c67c8b61866e9fc00#diff-e9c1ee46a19a8684d9d8d8a8c77f9005), but in previous `kafka-clients` versions for the same use case (`Errors.REQUEST_TIMED_OUT` on consumer) similar message (`Offset commit for group {} failed: {}`) was logged with `debug` level. 
as for me, it would be more logical to update log level to warning for such use case.

How to fix this issue? What could be the root cause? Maybe changing consumer properties or partition setup could help to get rid of such issue.

we use the following implementation for creating Kafka Streams:

```
StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
KStream<String, String> stream = builder.<String, String>stream(topicName);
stream.foreach((key, value) -> processMessage(key, value));
Topology topology = builder.build();
StreamsConfig streamsConfig = new StreamsConfig(consumerSettings);
new KafkaStreams(streamsTopology, streamsConfig);
```

our Kafka consumer settings:

```
bootstrap.servers: xxx1:9092,xxx2:9092,...,xxx5:9092
application.id: app
state.dir: /tmp/kafka-streams/xxx
commit.interval.ms: 5000       # also I tried default value 30000
key.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
value.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
timestamp.extractor: org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.WallclockTimestampExtractor
```

kafka broker version: `kafka_2.11-0.11.0.2`.
error occur on both versions of Kafka Streams: `1.0.1` and `1.1.0`.

Comment: Were you able to identify the problem? 
How did you solve this problem?

Comment: nope, still unclear what is the root cause. I guess it could be due to overloaded Kafka cluster, but not sure. anyway, it's not critical error, as Kafka streams retry an infinite number of times to commit offset, so you might only experience a small delay in processing of data.

Comment: @VasiliySarzhynskyi did you still not identify it?

Comment: @vanillaSugar unfortunately, nope

Comment: @VasiliySarzhynskyi and did you try various configurations? Do you also have these errors? : "This is not the correct coordinator" and "The coordinator is not aware of this member"

Comment: @VasiliySarzhynskyi have you tried increasing `offsets.commit.timeout.ms` broker property?

Comment: @KrzysztofZiomek that is a good question. Did you have a similar problem and maybe solved it?

Comment: For me, it happens under load/network congestion, these errors can be ignored, they are traced as warnings in Kafka 2.5.0 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7791

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have issue with Kafka cluster and Kafka consumer is get timed out while trying to commit offsets.
You can try to increase connection related configs for Kafka consumer

1. **request.timeout.ms** (by default 305000ms)

> The configuration controls the maximum amount of time the client will
>   wait for the response of a request

2. **connections.max.idle.ms** (by default 540000ms)

> Close idle connections after the number of milliseconds specified by
>   this config.

Comment: Your default values are wrong.
https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/consumer-configs.html

But actually, it's right way to fix it (I mean increase properties)